# How to pass args to wasm?

Tags: webassembly, emcc

I use emcc to complie a C++ code into js.
But how to pass args to C++ code?

```cpp
#include<iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (argc > 1)
    printf("%s", argv[1]);
}
```

build :

```
emcc ./test.cpp -sENVIRONMENT=shell -o test.js
```

pass commadline args into c code

Comment: I using d8 shell to run test.js

Answer (score 3):

It seems that this [stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/329626) answer is similar to your use-case:

Place

```js
Module['arguments'].push('first_param');
Module['arguments'].push('second_param');
```

before you run your function.

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    assert(argc == 3);
    assert(strcmp(argv[1], "first_param") == 0);
    assert(strcmp(argv[2], "second_param") == 0);
}
```

[Documentation reference](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/module.html#Module.arguments)

Edit:

So, I finally had time to install `d8`, and I made it work.

For me, in the generated `test.js`, there is this line:

```js
if (Module['arguments']) arguments_ = Module['arguments'];legacyModuleProp('arguments', 'arguments_');
```

You have to place the arguments before this, so it should look like:

```js
Module['arguments'] = [];
Module['arguments'].push('first_param');
Module['arguments'].push('second_param');

if (Module['arguments']) arguments_ = Module['arguments'];legacyModuleProp('arguments', 'arguments_');
```

You then compile with `emcc` and run with `d8`. I got another error because I did not end my `printf` call without a newline, so the output was not printing, a thing that seems to also happen in your code. Fortunately, there was an error message about the stdout not fully flushing, so I got to understand that was the problem.